# WordPress - Can you have Trailing Slashes for Pages but No Slashes for Posts?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, permalinks

A friend wants his WordPress site to have:

- Pages look like directories (to include a trailing slash - [www.domain.com/page/](http://www.domain.com/page/) )
- Blog posts to look like files (.html extension, no slash - [www.domain.com/post.html](http://www.domain.com/post.html) )
- and Products to look like files ( .html extension - [www.domain.com/products/product.html](http://www.domain.com/products/product.html) )

By default, WordPress will add the trailing slash for pages and posts.
Setting a custom permalink structure to **/%postname%.html** will add the extension to **blog posts**, but removes the trailing slash from pages, of course.

I'm able to get the product post-type to rewrite with add_permastruct

```
function rr_permastruct_html( $post_type, $args ) {
    // Works fine!
    if ( $post_type === 'product' )
        add_permastruct( $post_type, "{$args->rewrite['slug']}/%$post_type%.html", $args->rewrite );
    
    // Worth a shot, but no...   
    //if ( $post_type === 'page' )
    //    add_permastruct( $post_type, "{$args->rewrite['slug']}/%$post_type%/", $args->rewrite );
}
```

But when it comes to appending posts with the .html extension and still have pages keep the trailing slash, I keep running into walls.

I can't get it to work using .htaccess because it affects both. And my attempts with $wp_rewrite, after a while, have gone nowhere:

```
function rr_rewrite_page_permalink() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if (!strpos($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.html')) {
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.html';
        $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( $wp_rewrite->page_structure );
    }
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'rr_rewrite_page_permalink', -1);
```

Permalink plugins produce the same behaviors with no solution. So, is it even possible to have posts with .html extensions and have pages keep the trailing slash?

Thank you

Comment: > If you force a trailing slash on a file name, then that will cause the browser to think it is a folder and will result in a 404 error message. 
[Should You Have a Trailing Slash at the End of URLs?](https://searchfacts.com/url-trailing-slash/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have a tested and working solution for 404 problems. But in the spirit of the question, I am wondering if it is even possible in WordPress to have things set up this way?

Answer (score -1):

File names should not end in a trailing slash.

> If you force a trailing slash on a file name, then that will cause the browser to think it is a folder and will result in a 404 error message.
> [Should You Have a Trailing Slash at the End of URLs?](https://searchfacts.com/url-trailing-slash/)

And don't forget

> It can cause problems with duplicate content and crawl efficiency if your pages are accessible with and without a trailing slash.

Learn more about [Permalink for specific page name - WordPress Development Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191924/permalink-for-specific-page-name/259781)